# Mango fast app switching & heavy processing crash

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a WP7 app that sometimes has to make a long (5-25 sec) processing.

With Mango, when the app is set to Dormant state **while it was processing** (ex: the user presses the Windows button or locks the screen), when the user comes back, the app crashes.

I tried on the emulator and on my device, same behavior.

If I reproduce it in debug mode on Visual Studio, it doesn't crash so it's hard to find what is really happening.

To reproduce it, start a new Windows Phone project, add a button on MainPage.xaml & add an event handler on the click event that executes an infinite loop:

```
while (true)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

My question is: What is really happening? Why does it crash? Isn't fast app switching supposed to just pause the app process and resume it?

EDIT:
Another thing I noticed is that when running the heavy process, the deactivated & activated events do not seem to be raised when I get out/in the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer on the official Windows Phone forum ([link](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/89712/537210.aspx)). Here it is:

**Why it crashes:**

> From the time the app is deactivated, it has exactly ten seconds to
>   finish up what it is doing.  If the code takes more than ten seconds,
>   the OS will terminate the app.

**Why the deactivated & activated events are not raised when I get out/in the app:**

> If the process is blocking the UI thread this also blocks the message
>   dispatch loop so I suspect that this is the reason why your app never
>   gets a chance to detect and handle the events.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simple. WP7 cant really put your threads in a dormant state when you are under heavy processing in this fast time and will save a corrupt state. This state will crash when its reactivated.

It works in the debugger because the debugger makes everything slower and then WP7 has more time.

From Documentation:

When the user navigates forward, away from an application, after the Deactivated event is raised, the operating system will attempt to put the application into a dormant state. In this state, all of the application’s threads are stopped and no processing takes place, but the application remains intact in memory. If the application is reactivated from this state, the application does not need to re-create any state, because it has been preserved.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Where did you see that under heavy processing WP7 can't put threads in a dormant state?